# Is there any way to run a Windows-based Eclipse with a Linux-based Java SDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, cygwin, development-environment

I want to test my code against the (beta) IBM Java SDK 8.0, which will be a part of IBM Java products in future and support Java SE 8. The beta version is available for download [from here](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=swg-beta-ibmjte&S_PKG=dl&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8&dlmethod=http), but it's only available for Linux on x86 (/ x86_64), and not Windows. But my development environment is Windows. Of course, I could run the Java SDK through Cygwin or equivalent, so it's possible to execute the binaries, but is there any easy way to trigger them from an Eclipse instance running on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this. I would be surprised if it worked under Cygwin too.

The usual strategy for this type of problem is to create a Linux VM and test using that. There are free VM solutions around such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org).

Comment: Cygwin merely allows to compile linux software for windows by providing a compatibility layer - it can't execute native linux binaries either

Comment: Thanks for the info. I should have checked first that I can run IBM Java SDK 8.0 inside Cygwin - apparently not! So if I create a VM in VirtualBox and then map the host OS disk as a path in the VM, is there a way to remotely execute the Java binaries in the VM from Eclipse running inside my host machine?